# Dialog boxes in Marshmallow have transparent background

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow running on my phone and I have noticed a lot of GUI glitches in third-party apps, including my own apps.  The most common glitch seems to be that dialog boxes have a transparent background (Google’s own apps are fine, it is only third-party apps that are effected).

I have searched forums but struggled to find anyone else reporting similar problems so I am wondering whether I should wait until a newer build of Marshmallow is released before trying to tackle this issue.

Anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution, I was failing to add a theme to the AlertDialog builder.

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT)
```